# using lapply for nested loops

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have been learning a bit of `lapply` magic in `R`, but have not figured out how to replace nested loops -- is this also possible?

Here's my problem, and the nested-loop solution.

```
monCode <- c('F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'N', 
        'Q', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Z')
yearRange <- as.character(3:15)
yearRange[as.numeric(yearRange) < 10] <- as.character(paste0("0", yearRange[as.numeric(yearRange) < 10]))

outList <- vector()
for(Yr in yearRange) {
    for (mon in monCode) {
        outList <- c(outList, (paste0("IB", mon, Yr, " Comdty")))
    }
}
```

How would i do this using nested `lapply` functions, rather than nested loops?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for nested loops or nested lapply.

Use `expand.grid` to create all your combinations of `monCode` and `yearRange` then `do.call(sprintf,...)` to concatenate them

```
f <- expand.grid(monCode,yearRange)
outList <- do.call(sprintf, c(f, fmt = 'IB%s%s comdty'))
```

Comment: I get the error `Error in (function (fmt, ...)  : too few arguments` from the `do.call` line. I have been able to get something useable from `paste0("IB", f[,1], f[,2], " Comdty")` -- i don't understand `sprintf` enough to solve the issue. What's the bug?

Comment: The issue was using `list(...` instead of `c(...`.  See the edit.

Comment: +1 / accepted. thanks. The `expand.grid` trick out to eliminate most of my nested loops.