# How should multiple lapply be used for nested for loops with conditions?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table

I am new to R and do not really understand the lapply way to do things to speed up my code. Each outer loop takes about 2 mins which means it will be half a year before I finish running the loops.

I have searched other related posts but could not find much help e.g. these suggets not using lapply:
[using lapply for nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255449/using-lapply-for-nested-loops?rq=1)
[R convert nested for loop to lapply() for better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572872/r-convert-nested-for-loop-to-lapply-for-better-performance)
[Avoiding nested loops but iterate over 2 values using (l)apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151047/avoiding-nested-loops-but-iterate-over-2-values-using-lapply)

I have also seen these which seem to be what I need, but I dont get:

What function(x) is here:
[R - Basic understanding of using 'apply' instead of nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916999/r-basic-understanding-of-using-apply-instead-of-nested-loop)

What function(i) is here:
[Using apply family of functions to replace nested for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627697/using-apply-family-of-functions-to-replace-nested-for-loop-in-r)

I think I just need some sketch code/pseudo code to get me started working in the right direction. As of now, I am very lost with using lapply. For example in the structure below, how should I place the lapply 's?

Here I am simpliflying the code structure, hopefully I can make it clearer:

```
i=1
for (p in vector1) {
  
  k=1
  for (d in vector2) {
    
    if(k==1) {
      [DO SOMETHING]
      k=0
    } else {
      [DO SOMETHING]
    }
    
  }
  
  if (i==1) {
    [DO SOMETHING]
    i=0
  } else {
    [DO SOMETHING]
  }
  
}
```

Here is the code:

```
placeholder = data.table()
final_structure = data.table()

i=1
for (p in sort(unique(MFR_join$ID))) {

  k=1
  for (d in sort(unique(MFR_join$DRUG_NAME))) {

    if (k==1) {
    drug_data = fread(paste0("path_of_drug", d))[ID == p]
    trunk_patient = trunk[ID == p]
    final = merge.data.table(trunk_patient, drug_data, by = c("ID", "DATE"), all.x = T)
    k=0

    } else {
      drug_data = fread(paste0("path_of_drug", d))[ID == p]
      trunk_patient = trunk[ID == p]
      final = merge.data.table(final, drug_data, by = c("ID", "DATE"), all.x = T)
    }
  }
  
  if (i==1) {
    final = final[!apply(is.na(final[,3:42]), 1, all),]
    final_structure = rbind(placeholder, final)
    i=0
  } else {
    final = final[!apply(is.na(final[,3:42]), 1, all),]
    final_structure = rbind(final_structure, final)
  }

}
```

Here is what I am doing:

The inner loop reads in a drug file (out of 40 drug files) and filters for the patient (out of 130k patients) defined from the outer loop.

The trunk variable holds all ID's and daily dates (2013-2019). The trunk is also filtered for the patient defined from the outer loop. This is used so that the drug's joined to trunk are like branches.

Each of the 40 drug files are then left-joined to this trunk on (ID, DATE), bringing over the column drug_MFR_category.
This is the "final" variable, which will have 42 columns (ID, DATE, + 40 drug_MFR_category columns).

In the outer loop, for the "final" variable, if all the 40 drug_MFR_category columns are NA for a particular row, we remove the rows. And each iteration of this "final" variable for each patient is rbinded to form the "final_structure".

I am looping through each patient, then each drug, then joining all drugs to each patient, remove NA's for each patient, then bind each patient recursively. This is because if I only loop through drugs and join onto trunk, there will be too many NA's after about 15 joins and before I join in all 40 drugs, my R will have hung.

All the drugs have to be joined to patients before I can remove NA's as I am only removing NA's if all 40 drug columns on the row are NA. But the joined file will be too large if I do not split up the patients and remove NA's before rbinding them, and therefore I looped through patients.

Here are some sample data:
I am not sure how the sample data can be more helpful. Please let me know how.

MFR_Join:

```
        ID           DRUG_NAME
      1: 1           DAPAGLIFLOZIN
      2: 1           METFORMIN
      3: 2           DAPAGLIFLOZIN
      4: 2           METFORMIN
```

trunk:

```
          ID             DATE
        1: 1           2013-01-01
        ---            ---
     2555: 1           2019-12-31
     2556: 2           2013-01-01
        ---            ---
     5110: 2           2019-12-31
```

a drug data file looks like this:

```
        ID                   DATE DAPAGLIFLOZIN_MFR_CATEGORY
       1: 1           2013-01-01                           1
       2: 1           2016-01-01                           0
       3: 1           2019-12-31                           0
       4: 2           2013-01-01                           1
       5: 2           2019-12-31                           0
```

another drug data file looks like this:

```
       ID                   DATE  METFORMIN_MFR_CATEGORY
       1: 1           2013-01-01                       0
       2: 1           2019-12-31                       1
       3: 2           2013-01-01                       0
       5: 2           2019-12-31                       1
```

final for ID 1 looks like this (created by left joins of drug files onto filtered ID's trunk - inner for loop)

```
       ID             DATE        DAPAGLIFLOZIN_MFR_CATEGORY   METFORMIN_MFR_CATEGORY
       1: 1           2013-01-01                           1                   0
       2: 1           2013-01-02                          NA                  NA
       ---            ---                                ---                 ---
    1094: 1           2015-12-31                          NA                  NA
    1095: 1           2016-01-01                           0                  NA
    1096: 1           2016-01-02                          NA                  NA
       ---            ---                                ---                 ---
    2554: 1           2019-12-30                          NA                  NA
    2555: 1           2019-12-31                           0                   1
```

final for ID 2 looks like this (created by left joins of drug files onto filtered ID's trunk - inner for loop)

```
       ID             DATE        DAPAGLIFLOZIN_MFR_CATEGORY   METFORMIN_MFR_CATEGORY
       1: 2           2013-01-01                           0                   1
       2: 2           2013-01-02                          NA                  NA
       ---            ---                                ---                 ---
    2554: 2           2019-12-30                          NA                  NA
    2555: 2           2019-12-31                           0                   0
```

final_structure looks like this (rbinding final recursively, after clearing out NA rows in drug columns - outer for loop)

```
       ID             DATE        DAPAGLIFLOZIN_MFR_CATEGORY   METFORMIN_MFR_CATEGORY
       1: 1           2013-01-01                           1                   0
       2: 1           2016-01-01                           0                  NA
       2: 1           2019-12-31                           0                   1
       3: 2           2013-01-01                           1                   0
       4: 2           2019-12-31                           0                   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**.  Do one thing, `right_join` trunk with first_drug table.  this will remove all NAs.  Now use this as `.init` in `reduce`.  Further change `left_join` to `full_join` in function argument in `reduce` so that only non-NA values will be added.  Try it.

Still I am not sure what you are after.  Till now I have understood that you need an outcome like your `final_structure`.  But what do `MFR_join` table is doing, I am not able to understand.  You may try the following syntax and tell if it served the purpose. I am using `purrr::reduce`.  You can however use baseR's `Reduce` similarly but with a rearrangement of arguments.

## sample data creation

```
drug1 <- read.table(text = "ID                   DATE  DAPAGLIFLOZIN_MFR_CATEGORY
       1 1           2013-01-01                           1
       2 1           2016-01-01                           0
       3 1           2019-12-31                           0
       4 2           2013-01-01                           1
       5 2           2019-12-31                           0", header = T)

drug2 <- read.table(text = " ID                   DATE  METFORMIN_MFR_CATEGORY
       1 1           2013-01-01                       0
       2 1           2019-12-31                       1
       3 2           2013-01-01                       0
       4 2           2019-12-31                       1     ", header = T)

drug3 <- read.table(text = "ID                   DATE  ABCD_MFR_CATEGORY
       1 1           2013-01-01                           1
       2 1           2016-01-02                           0
       3 1           2019-12-31                           0
       4 2           2013-01-01                           1
       5 2           2019-12-31                           0", header = T)

trunk <- read.table(text = "ID             DATE
        1 1           2013-01-01
        2 1           2019-12-31
        3 2           2013-01-01
        4 2           2019-12-31", header = T)

trunk %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
  complete(DATE = seq.Date(min(DATE), max(DATE), by = "days")) %>%
  ungroup() -> trunk

drug1 <- drug1 %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE))
drug2 <- drug2 %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE))
drug3 <- drug3 %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE))
```

## updated code in view of fresh request by OP.

*Note: I was already in doubt what purpose does the two tables (MFR_join and Trunk serve here.*

Do just this.

```
reduce(list(drug1, drug2, drug3), ~full_join(.x, .y, by = c("ID" = "ID", "DATE" = "DATE")))

  ID       DATE DAPAGLIFLOZIN_MFR_CATEGORY METFORMIN_MFR_CATEGORY ABCD_MFR_CATEGORY
1  1 2013-01-01                          1                      0                 1
2  1 2016-01-01                          0                     NA                NA
3  1 2019-12-31                          0                      1                 0
4  2 2013-01-01                          1                      0                 1
5  2 2019-12-31                          0                      1                 0
6  1 2016-01-02                         NA                     NA                 0
```

## Earlier code

```
library(tidyverse)
reduce(list(drug2, drug3), 
       .init = trunk %>% right_join(drug1, by = c("ID" = "ID", "DATE" = "DATE")),
       ~ full_join(.x, .y, by = c("ID" = "ID", "DATE" = "DATE"))
       )
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID DATE       DAPAGLIFLOZIN_MFR_CATEGORY METFORMIN_MFR_CATEGORY ABCD_MFR_CATEGORY
  <int> <date>                          <int>                  <int>             <int>
1     1 2013-01-01                          1                      0                 1
2     1 2016-01-01                          0                     NA                NA
3     1 2019-12-31                          0                      1                 0
4     2 2013-01-01                          1                      0                 1
5     2 2019-12-31                          0                      1                 0
6     1 2016-01-02                         NA                     NA                 0
```

Explanation of logic.

- Since your `trunk` table has every possible date for every patient id, if you'll left_join with any other table, all `NA`s will be evidently included in result.
- I have used `reduce` function which actually takes first element of the first argument and operates it upon with second element in that same argument.  The result is then operated upon on next element in the list. and so on.  In the last we will have a final element on which same operation has been carried out iteratively.  for e.g. If `+` is carried out on a list of numbers in `reduce` the result will be same that of `sum()`.
- If `.init` is supplied optionally, it actually takes it as first element and carries the operation with first element in argument and so on.  for e.g. If I will pass .init = 5, to a vector say 1:5 into reduce, I will get 20 as a result.
- Now since first element (.init) is right joined data with first drug table it takes out all NAs and keep only non-NA rows.
- In all the next iterations, non-NA rows keep on adding till the last drug table.
- So filter need is also eliminated.
- But only keep in mind to remove drug1 table from the first arugument i.e. list of drug tables in `reduce`.

I hope this clears the things.

Comment: Hi Anil, thanks! I have tried to use this way; left join drugs on trunk without going through ID first to clear out NA's. The file size became too large for my R Server. And this is because there are too many NA's before I can join in all 40 drugs. So what I was doing was to go through each patient for each drug and cut down the NA's first, before I bind them back to the final structure. To go through each ID and each drug I need data from MFR_join. Hope this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Too many NA's in final_structure before I can complete all 40 joins, so my R server hangs. In your suggestion, the filtering of NA's come after joining all the drugs, it would not be feasible because NA's will be too much. So I have to remove NA's by by patient first, this happens after joining all drugs to each patient and before binding the patients into final_structure. (edit of previous comment which I will delete)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will try it now.

Comment: Hi Anil, thanks once again for the suggestion. I think it works and takes less time than the loops. I wonder if you can walk me through what happened in the code in more detail?

Comment: Hi Anil, thanks again for the suggestion. I think there is an issue with my R server for example, if I run it on the first 10 drugs, I am able to finish it in 240s, but when I run it on the first 20 drugs, I get an error about multiple browsers accessing the server. In order to avoid this problem, is it possible to split up the 40 drugs in batches of 10 and then join them back again in some way?

Comment: Hi Anil, can you explain further the use of trunk in your code? Trunk only has the 2 columns, which are used to join with drug1,drug2,... it seems like it does not serve a purpose. The reason I needed to use it was because I need to find which rows have drug columns all NA in the end after joining all 40 drugs.

Comment: I told you earlier that I am not aware of `MFR` and `trunk` table use in this code. In my humble opinion things got complicated because of inclusion of these two tables.  Otherwise it would have been a simple Reduce or reduce problem

Comment: Hi Anil, I mean that it seems like it does not serve a purpose to the code you've suggested. I am thinking that just full join serves my purpose, right?

Comment: Yes, the reduce for all drug tables seems better strategy. Should I modify my answer then?

Comment: Hi Anil, yeah. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anil, could you update the code? Thanks!